# Finding a needle (user input) in a haystack (Array)

Tags: java

I am trying to create a program that determines whether a user input is found in an array.

I am to then output the position of the integer in the array.

It looks like my program is not pulling anything from my main.

Here is the program:

```
public static int returnIndex(int[ ] haystack, int needle) {    
    for (int n : haystack) {       
        if (haystack[needle] == n )  {       
        } else {
            System.out.println("Element not found in array");                   
            System.exit(0);             
       }
      }
      return needle;        
    }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     int[] haystack = { 4,5,6,7,12,13,15,16,22,66,99,643 };        
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter a number in the array: ");                
     int needle = sc.nextInt(); 
   }
 }
```

Comment: Your logics a little backwards, rather than returning on the first mismatch value, you should be returning on the first match value, BUT, you should be using the long form of the `for-loop` so you know the index :P

Comment: For the record: I put in some more information into my answer ... and I think: you wont see much other input; so consider accepting/upvoting (as you will then reach upvote level ;-) the answer that you find the most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You are looping the wrong way.

Use a counting for loop

```
for (int index=0; index haystack.length; index++) {
...
```

instead! Then you compare `haystack[index]` against `needle`, and return `index` on a match.

Please note: actually, using the "for each" loop style as you do in your question is good practice - that should be the "first" thought when writing down a loop to iterate items of an array/collection. But sometimes you simply need to know that `index`; and then the counting-for is the right choice.

Comment: So I would do something like `for (int index=0; index<11; index++)`?

Answer (score 0):

You should be looping through the indices of the Array, not the values. Once you find an index that returns the value you wish to use you can pull it. However, if the Array is sorted this can be simplified using an algorithm. The simplest way I can think of doing this would be do go to halfway through the Array and check if the value is larger, smaller, or the same, and then cutting half between that and the next larger or smaller one respective to your result until you find your answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Solutions

To solve it like this you need to keep track of the index and compare each value with the `needle` like this *(returning `-1` if not in array)*:

```
public static int returnIndex(int[] haystack, int needle) {

    int index = 0;
    for (int n : haystack) {
        if(n == needle) return index;
        index++;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

if you want to approach this using indices then it would look like this:

```
public static int returnIndex(int[] haystack, int needle) {

    for (int n = 0; n < haystack.length; n++) {

        if (haystack[n] == needle) {
            return n;
        }

    }

    return -1;
}
```

## Bugs in your code

your for loop is iterating the values of `haystack` and not the indices also your use of `haystack[needle]` is checking for the value at an index of `needle` which could be a potential `indexoutofbounds`. Additionally you exit out of the program immediately if the `needle` isn't located at the first location of the array.

```
public static int returnIndex(int[] haystack, int needle) {

    // iterates each value of haystack
    for (int n : haystack) {
        // this checks for a value at index needle, if needle were 300 it
        // looks for haystack[300]
        // if haystack were a 10 index array it would lead to an error
        if (haystack[needle] == n) {

        }
        // using this else statement will lead to exiting program
        // the first time `haystack[needle] == n` is false this function
        // finishes
        else {
            System.out.println("Element not found in array");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    return needle;
}
```

Comment: Ahhh.. I understand how I thought wrong now. Thank you for your time and explanation

Comment: Responding to the the bugs in my code; the purpose of the program is to either output the integers index or display a message and then exit the program.

Comment: since you put the message as an `else` statement directly in the for loop, it doesn't check the other elements of the array for the needle if it is not in the first index because of `System.exit(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think `needle` is the user input number which you are going to find it in your `array` and want to print the position. If I have gone to the right way than **change**

`if (haystack[needle] == n )` to `if (haystack[n] == needle )`

and `return n` for the number position. and using the **counting loop** as **@GhostCat** described before. where `n` is the `index`